# How to set an image on the background in Kivy (Python) before the content is loaded?

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing the weather application at KIVY in which when starting the weather page is running and the label label is set to the temperature value. Also at startup, before the parceling begins, I set the image on the background of the entire screen. But when I run the application, no images, it is loaded only after the parsing works. How do I make the installation of the image before the parsing begins?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

Builder.load_file('my.kv')

class MainWidget(RelativeLayout):
    intWeather = 0
    
    def __init__(self, ** kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, 
self).__init__( ** kwargs) 
        with self.canvas.before:
    
Rectangle(source='winter.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=Window.size) 
    
        strWeather = self.set_weather()
        self.ids['weather'].text = strWeather+" °C"
        self.intWeather = int(strWeather)  
    
    def set_weather(self):
        url = 'https://pogoda33.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC/14-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
        weather = soup.find_all('div', class_='forecast-weather-temperature')
        return weather[0].text[0:3]

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # return a MainWidget() as a root widget
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Here the class MyApp is initialized
    # and its run() method called.
    myApp().run()
```

my.kv file

```
<MainWidget>:
    Label:  
        id: weather      
        font_size:150
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.8}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image is not showing up as soon as you would like because the `__init__()` method of the `MainWidget` is using the main thread to access the web and retrieve the weather. The kivy `App` also uses the main thread to update the GUI, so it cannot do its update until you release the main thread. As a general rule, you should not do any long running processing on the main thread of a kivy application. So, to fix this, do your web access in another thread:

```
class MainWidget(RelativeLayout):
    intWeather = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Rectangle(source='winter.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=Window.size)
        # run web access in another thread
        Thread(target=self.set_weather, daemon=True).start()

    @mainthread
    def show_weather(self, temp):
        # this gets run on the main thread
        self.ids['weather'].text = temp + " °C"
        self.intWeather = int(temp)

    def set_weather(self):
        url = 'https://pogoda33.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC/14-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
        weather = soup.find_all('div', class_='forecast-weather-temperature')
        temp = weather[0].text[0:3]
        self.show_weather(temp)
```